# How can I disable / deactivate / delete a discourse user account via php?

Tags: php, discourse

I use for my discourse site my own registration and [SSO](https://meta.discourse.org/t/official-single-sign-on-for-discourse/13045) via [discourse-api-php](https://github.com/discoursehosting/discourse-api-php) and LDAP. Is there some option how to disable, deactive or delete user via php? Because when I delete/deactive user account in LDAP, user profil at discourse portal is still active and I wanna have every user-management on one page.

Comment: downvote isn't answer

Comment: The question is too open,Can you show your code or what you have done for the problem?

Comment: I havent find any option how to disable/deactive/delete outside of discourse administration. So its reason why I asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://meta.discourse.org/t/suspend-a-user-via-the-api/36810) the route to suspend a user is

```
/admin/users/:user_id/suspend
```

The controller for this is [here](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb#L51) - it accepts the parameters `duration` and `reason`.

This function isn't in the library you are using, so you'll need to add it yourself to use it.